# Incomplete Type InNested Name Specifier JUCE

Tags: c++, juce

I'm having a problem with circular dependencies when trying to manage my windows with a 'WindowList' class. When I want to close a window with closeButtonPressed code below, I need to remove the object from the windowList file, however I am including WindowSetter in the WindowList file. Previous errors like this have been solvable through a forward declaration, however I am not sure how to solve this one. Anny suggestions?
(full code can be viewed here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7d43c6d5b2cf1fef618be9f75077ad0c)

```
#pragma once

#include "../JuceLibraryCode/JuceHeader.h"
#include "WindowList.h"
class WindowList;

class WindowSetter  : public DialogWindow
{
public:
WindowSetter (const String& title,
             Component* content,
             bool shouldBeResizeable,
             int initWidth, int initHeight,
             int minWidth, int minHeight,
             int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
:   DialogWindow (title, Colours::white, true, true),
    owner (this)
{
    setUsingNativeTitleBar (true);
    setResizable (true, true);
    setResizeLimits (minWidth, minHeight, maxWidth, maxHeight);
    setContentOwned (content, false);

    setVisible (true);


}

~WindowSetter()
{
}

void closeButtonPressed() override
{
    WindowList::getWindowList();        // ERROR: Incomplete type 'WindowList' named in nested name specifier
    owner = nullptr;
}

bool escapeKeyPressed() override
{
    return true;
}

private:
JUCE_DECLARE_NON_COPYABLE_WITH_LEAK_DETECTOR (WindowSetter)

ScopedPointer<Component> owner;
};
```

[image]

edit: Added the full code for the file causing the error and an error log screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OMGtechy's response addresses the question that you asked, but I'd like to recommend a different design that:

1. Eliminates the need to worry about cyclic dependencies
2. Is more idiomatic JUCE code.

The design as you have it here tightly couples things together. A more JUCE-y way to solve the problem is you use the `ChangeBroadcaster` / `ChangeListener` classes to remove that tight coupling. When you add a `WindowSetter` to your `WindowList`, also subscribe to its change messages. When the user clicks on the close button, the `WindowSetter` sets a boolean and alerts anyone listening to it that it's been updated.

In sketches, it looks like

```
class WindowSetter : public DialogWindow
                   , public ChangeBroadcaster

{
public:
   WindowSetter( /*(etc...)*/)
   : DialogWindow(...)
   , owner(this)
   , wantsToClose(false)
   {
      // etc

   }

   void closeButtonPressed() override
   {
      wantsToClose = true;
      // notify observers that we've changed. 
      sendChangeMessage();
   }

   bool windowWantsToClose() const 
   {
      return wantstoClose;
   }

private:
   bool wantsToClose;
};


class WindowList : public ChangeListener 
{

   void addWindowSetterToList(WindowSetter* wnd)
   {
      wnd->addChangeListener(this)
      windows.addIfNotAlreadyThere(wnd);
   }

   void changeListenerCallback(ChangeBroadcaster* src) override 
   {
      // cast from the ChangeBroadcaster base class to our WindowSetter class.
      WindowSetter* wnd = dynamic_cast<WindowSetter*>(src);
      if (nullptr != wnd)
      { 
         // if we contain the object, and the object wants to be closed...
         if (windows.contains(wnd) && wnd->windowWantsToClose())
         {
            // get rid of it. 
            windows.remove(wnd);
         }
      }
   }

};
```

You'll see this kind of design used almost everywhere in JUCE codebases.

Comment: This is exactly the sort of solution I'm looking for! Still quite new to JUCE/ anything more than hello world in C++

Comment: Time spent reading the source of the JUCE examples will pay off over and over.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at your code from the perspective of an imaginary compiler to find out what's going on...

```
// NOTE: we're in WindowSetter.h

#include "WindowList.h"
```

Sure thing, let's go take a look at that file and include it in here...

```
// NOTE: we're in WindowList.h

#include "WindowSetter.h"
```

Sure thing, let's go take a look...

```
// NOTE: we're back in WindowSetter.h

#include "WindowList.h"
```

But ... I was just doing that. Oh god, I'm in an infinite loop. HELP!

***KABOOM***

The compiler can't include the headers you're asking for, because they both require each other in an infinite loop. You need to break this cycle by not including the headers in this recursive manner.

Forward declarations, which you already know about, can be useful for this. The reason is because they can inform the compiler about a type name without you having to include the header. This is great if the compiler just needs to know about the type name, but nothing else (such as size, for example).

The problem you've got here though, architectural issues aside, is that you're using the internals of `WindowList` inside `WindowSetter` here:

```
    WindowList::getWindowList();        // ERROR: Incomplete type 'WindowList' named in nested name specifier
```

This is probably why you ended up including the header in the first place; if you didn't it'd give you a similar error.

To work around this, you can move the definition of the member function `closeButtonPressed()` outside of the header file and into a .cpp file. You'll probably want to move the other functions too for consistencies sake too (a matter of personal opinion).

Once you've done that, you'll no longer be using the details of `WindowList` inside `WindowSetter.h` anymore, and will therefore be able to stop including it.

This will solve your problem, unless there are other cyclic dependencies hidden elsewhere (I haven't read through it all).

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed explanation OMGtech! I figured the problem was to do with the way I was using the included, but wasn't sure what the 'standard' way of approaching such a problem was. Any suggestions for in the future to avoid having to deal with these problems in the first place?

Comment: I think that @bgporter has covered that for the most part :) One extra thing you can think about though is interfaces; define an interface, and have your class take an object of unknown type that conforms to this interface. That way, you don't care  what class you're getting, you care about what it can do. Other than that, just makes mistakes like this and learn from them ;) mistakes are opportunities, not abhorrent monsters.